# Different RCUs per region for dynamo db global tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamo db global tables for one of my services and it is provisioned with same RCUS/WCUS(rWCUs) for all regions as per the general recommendations. I am not using the on-demand mode.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_reqs_bestpractices.html#globaltables_reqs_bestpractices.tables

I understand that the WCUs should be kept consistent across regions to allow writes to replicate. However, the read traffic for my service varies quite a lot across regions. So I was wondering if it is ok to configure different RCUs per region? The documentation doesn't specifically mention anything about RCUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to keep different RCUs in different regions. Typical use cases is active passive multi-region architecture.

But If failover from one region to another region is automatic, you should make sure that passive region will be able to take care of the burst of traffic.